# How to see the message that I sent while sharing the Google Docs

Tags: google-docs, notifications

I shared a Google Docs with few of my contacts. While sharing the file, I had an option to send a message. I added a message but I want to check what I sent.

How can I see that message?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to search for those messages, you need to make the following selection before sending the message:

[image]

Afterwards you can search for the following:

> in:sent "(via Google Docs)"

If you didn't tick the *send a copy to myself* box, there's no way of retrieving those messages. All messages are being send in the background via this e-mail adres:

> doclist.bounces.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to one of your recipients and ask them to forward the message that went to their email when you shared the doc.